# Find $f(x), g(x)$ if $f(x) \sim g(x),\ \int_a^\infty f(x) \,dx$ - convergent, $\int_a^\infty g(x) \,dx$ - divergent.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I need to find an example of two functions $f(x), g(x)$:

$f(x)\sim g(x),\
\int_a^\infty f(x) \,dx$ - convergent, $\int_a^\infty g(x) \,dx$ - divergent.

It's easy to prove that if $f(x), g(x) > 0,$ $ f(x)\sim g(x) \text{ as }x\to +\infty$ then both integrals are convergent of both integrals are divergent. Same goes for $f(x), g(x) < 0.$ I don't really see how it's possible to find an example of these functions so I must be missing something.

Comment: What is the meaning of the relation $\sim$?

Comment: I agree that a proper definition of $\sim$ would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you put no further conditions on $a$ I will assume $a\in\mathbb{R}$. You also did not define $\sim$ properly, so I will assume that this means asymptotic equivalence:
$$f\sim g \iff \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$$

Choose $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+\kappa_1}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x^2-\kappa_2},$ where $\kappa_1>a^2$ and $\kappa_2>a^2$ are constants. It can be easily shown that $f\sim g$. Furhermore
$$\int_a^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+\kappa_1}dx$$ is convergent, whereas
$$\int_a^\infty\frac{1}{x^2-\kappa_2}dx$$
is divergent since we are integrating over a pole.

Answer (score 0):

Choose $\ \ f(x)=\dfrac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}} \ $ , $\ \ \ g(x)=\dfrac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}} +\dfrac{\sin^2 x}{x} \ $.

We have:

$f(x)\underset{+\infty}{\sim} g(x) \ \  $ , $\ \int_{\pi}^{+\infty} f(x) dx \ $ is convergent , $\ \int_{\pi}^{+\infty} g(x) dx \ $ is divergent