Integrals of asymptotic functions
If $f\sim g$ then these two integrals $$\int_a^{\infty}f(x)dx\text{ and } \int_a^{\infty}g(x)dx$$ are either both convergent or both divergent.
Is this theorem correct? I have doubts because I think I found a counterexample,
A comparison test is enough to prove that $$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x}}dx$$ converges. While $$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\cos^2x}{x}dx$$ diverges. That means their sum $$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{\cos^2x}{x}dx$$ diverges. But notice that $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{\cos^2x}{x}}{\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x}}}=1$$
In other words $$\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{\cos^2x}{x}\sim\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x}}$$ but as we've seen the first integral diverges while the second converges.
So what's going on? Is the Theorem false or I'm missing some conditions?

The theorems all require some form of monotonicity or a constant sign (or an absolute value in certain cases suffices and this time it does not). Your first integrand oscillates between positive and negative, therefore the use of the limit comparison test is invalid.

Similar example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4080903/42969
